# How to validate decimal no using ng-pattern in angularJs?

Tags: regex, angularjs, validation

I want to validate decimal no like 0.5,0.05 and also natural no.

For natural no I used this pattern `/^[0-9]{1,7}$/`.

What pattern I will use for decimal no and natural no together?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this should work.
          `/^[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]+)?$/`

Answer (score 0):

Use this `/^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d*)?$/`